# Using D3 with Shiny - Collapsible Tree?

Tags: d3.js, shiny

I have a fair understanding of Shiny and R but I'm just getting started with Javascript and have never coded in HTML or CSS. I would like to learn to build a collapsible tree using D3.js ( Something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033)) Is there any tutorial that I can refer to get started with integrating D3.js into Shiny?

I have come across the [CollapsibeTree package](https://github.com/AdeelK93/collapsibleTree) but I would like to learn how to build one myself. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

here is the minimap example using the `diamonds` dataset. You can find more examples here https://github.com/AdeelK93/collapsibleTree

```
library(shiny)
#install.packages("collapsibleTree")
library(collapsibleTree)

data(diamonds,package = "ggplot2")
subdiamonds <- diamonds[1:300,]

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    collapsibleTreeOutput("tree")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$tree <- renderCollapsibleTree({
    collapsibleTree(
      subdiamonds,
      hierarchy = c("cut", "color","price"),
      width = 800
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But I would like to make changes to how the tree looks so I can zoom into the tree or highlight a particular path or disable a branch. And I cannot do this with the R package. So I would like to build my own js to do all these with my tree, but I'm kind of stuck at going forward with this. I know I need to write a .js file and a .html file that has the css parameters. But how can I combine this to my R code?

Comment: Well, since your original post didn't include any of the above information, You should be more clear what you want to achieve with this package. Please provide a guided reference (with your own code) what you have considered/done so far

Comment: I do not want to use this package at all, I want to build a visualization like this that works with R (Shiny) And I'm looking for a tutorial on how to get started. Thank you!

Comment: you can also try the [d3Tree](https://github.com/metrumresearchgroup/d3Tree) package that lets you pan/zoom the tree.